# Programmatically created TranslateAnimation ignoring my setStartOffset()

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a static method that, given a ViewGroup container, basically animates all the child views. Each view gets animated with the same `TranslateAnimation` object, which I'm creating programmatically.
However, I wanted to implement some kind of delay between the animation of each view, given by a `delayMillis` input parameter:

```
public static void slideInChilds(ViewGroup container, long delayMillis, int... childsAt) {

    // ... stuff

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(type, fromX, type, toX, type, fromY, type, toY);
    anim.setDuration(200);
    anim.setFillEnabled(true); anim.setFillAfter(true); anim.setFillBefore(true);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    for (int k : childsAt) {
        anim.setStartOffset(k * delayMillis);
        container.getChildAt(k).startAnimation(anim);

        //OR:
        //container.getChildAt(k).startAnimation(anim);
        //anim.setStartOffset(anim.getStartOffset() + delayMillis)
    }
}
```

So basically I'm iterating over an array of views (index) and each time I increment `setStartOffset()` by a `delayMillis` amount. As you can see I went two different ways (`currentOffset + delay` or `k * delay`), but none of them worked: I see the child views moving together, as if delay was set to 0.

I checked out these values, and they are what I expect them to be (i.e., I'm really calling `setStartOffset(0)`, `setStartOffset(200)`, `setStartOffset(400)` and so on). Also, if I have five childs, they all start when the maximum delay is reached, after a whole second. It's like each call to `setStartOffset()` invalidates the `startAnimation()` call, until I reach the last object, when they all start together.

Why this is not working?

Comment: try instantiating a new TranslateAnimation at each iteration

Comment: I found it working that way, but was wondering what's wrong with this code. Couldn't find anything in official docs.

Comment: once the first animation is started, the startOffset parameter is not take in consideration anymore. It is just a speculation